# Can the United Nations security council deploy forces in areas of conflict without consent from a rebel group?

Tags: armed-conflict, united-nations, unsc, peacekeeping

On a United Nations site for, [DEPLOYING PEACEKEEPERS](https://peacekeeping.un.org/en/deploying-peacekeepers), it said that

> As a conflict develops, worsens, or approaches resolution, the UN is frequently involved in a number of consultations to determine the best response by the international community. These consultations would likely involve
>
> - All relevant United Nations actors
> - The potential host government **and the parties on the ground**

Does this mean that the consent of a rebel force (not recognized by the  UN), which is in control of a region, is required to deploy UN peacekeeping forces by a UNSC Resolution?

Comment: Having consultations does not mean gaining consent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the consent of the belligerents to bring in UN forces is not expected, if it comes to that. It is required is to try other options before escalating to use of force.

Deployment of force by the UNSC is covered by [Chapter VII](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/chapter-7) of the UN Charter. [Chapter VI](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/chapter-6), on settlement of disputes, would also be relevant.

The text of the charter is very high level, so literature on how it is interpreted should be a topic for further search.

Answer (score 15):

I was a UN peacekeeper in Western Sahara ([MINURSO](https://peacekeeping.un.org/en/mission/minurso)) back in 2009-2010, and I recall from the briefings that there are (at least) two distinct kinds of peace operations: peace *keeping* and peace *enforcement*, with the former requiring the explicit consent of the belligerent parties.

And the situation does not seem to have changed since then; quoting from the UN official page on [Principles of Peacekeeping](https://peacekeeping.un.org/en/principles-of-peacekeeping) (emphasis mine):

> These three principles are inter-related and mutually reinforcing:
>
> 1. **Consent of the parties**
> 2. Impartiality
> 3. Non-use of force except in self-defence and defence of the mandate
>
> ##### 1. Consent of the parties
>
> UN peacekeeping operations are deployed **with the consent of the main
> parties to the conflict**. This requires a commitment by the parties to
> a political process. Their acceptance of a peacekeeping operation
> provides the UN with the necessary freedom of action, both political
> and physical, to carry out its mandated tasks.
>
> In the absence of such consent, a peacekeeping operation risks
> becoming a party to the conflict; and being drawn towards enforcement
> action, and away from its fundamental role of keeping the peace.

Peace *enforcement*, on the other hand, does **not** require consent; from the relevant [terminology](https://peacekeeping.un.org/en/terminology) page (where other peace activities are also briefly described):

> Peace enforcement involves the application of a range of coercive
> measures, including the use of military force. It requires the
> explicit authorization of the Security Council.
>
> It is used to restore international peace and security in situations
> where the Security Council has decided to act in the face of a threat
> to the peace, breach of the peace or act of aggression. The Council
> may utilize, where appropriate, regional organizations and agencies
> for enforcement action under its authority and in accordance with the
> UN Charter.

See also the relevant lemma at the [Encyclopedia Princetoniensis](https://pesd.princeton.edu/node/561) (again, emphasis mine):

> Peacekeeping forces are normally deployed with **the consent of the
> parties to a conflict** and in support of a ceasefire or other agreed
> upon peace measures. [...] Peace enforcement refers to the use of military
> assets to **enforce a peace against the will of the parties to a
> conflict** when, for instance, a ceasefire has failed.

where, interestingly enough, it is also noted:

> there is no explicit UN Charter basis for peacekeeping.  UN peacekeeping emerged during the Cold War as a pragmatic, ad hoc response to conflicts between states where the warring parties were willing to accept the deployment of a neutral third party to help keep the peace and to prevent the resumption of fighting while diplomacy could be pursued to resolve the conflict.

Up until the 90's, and with the exception of the outlier case of the Korean War, UN peace operations were exclusively peace-keeping ones, thus requiring the explicit consent of the belligerents. In the 90's there were cases were the line was not so clear (most notably in former Yugoslavia, Rwanda, and Somalia), and (again, according to [Encyclopedia Princetoniensis](https://pesd.princeton.edu/node/561))

> UN Secretary-General Boutros Boutros-Ghali, [...] in 1992 called for the establishment of “peace-enforcement units” to deal with challenges that exceed peacekeeping, but such units have never been created. National and multinational forces, such as those of the North Atlantic Treaty Organization (NATO), have sometimes been called upon instead to assist UN peacekeeping operations with enforcement.

The idea of peace enforcement operations [did not sit well](https://www.jstor.org/stable/161981), and there were never widely adopted; AFAIK, all the current UN peace operations are peace-keeping ones, deployed with the explicit consent of the belligerent parties.

---

To summarize: it *can*, but it normally does not do so, and it has done so only in very few cases in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The invasion of Kuwait and Iraq in 1991 was a UN-authorised operation, and obviously did not have the consent of the Iraqi government. So it’s clear that such consent is not necessarily required.

Comment: The question body makes explicit that the question is about "*UN **peacekeeping** forces*", and such forces are by definition under the command of the UN, not of the contributing countries. An authorization by the UNSC of a military operation, such as the one you mention here, is  a different case altogether and arguably irrelevant to the question.